# FTS Alfresco OR not working on empty property

Tags: full-text-search, alfresco

I am executing a query against Alfresco using FTS. I want to find files that have my:property empty. This is part of my query:

```
AND (ISNULL:"my:property" OR ISUNSET:"my:property" OR =my:property:"")
```

When testing I discovered that this will not find my file when my:property is set to an empty string. When I change the query to this it does find that file:

```
AND (=my:property:"")
```

It seems to me that the OR statements aren't executed appropriately.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I'm using Alfresco Community 5.1f

Comment: Please try relevant query from https://blog.dbi-services.com/alfresco-some-useful-database-queries/ it will fetch you most relevant search results based on properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @kintu but I would rather use FTS queries, they should support Transactional Metadata Queries using (only) the database. What's the advantage of DB queries over FTS?

Comment: Have you made your property tokenised by  adding <tokenised>both</tokenised> ? If not then please try after adding this. It will index your property and make it searchable.

Comment: I'd also rather not use the index. I would like to use an FTS query that can go completely via the database.

Comment: It seems that ISNULL can behave unexpectedly in transactional metadata queries. As stated [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html). ISUNSET also doesn't behave as expected. 

I also found that FTS only supports a number of special fields ([source](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/query-lang-support.html)):

 [PARENT, TYPE, ASPECT, EXACTTYPE, EXACTASPECT]